# OneDrive API Button not opening window?

Tags: onedrive

I'm new to the OneDrive API and I cannot figure out why a window doesn't pop open when I call the function? I get no error logs in the console window either.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.live.net/v7.0/OneDrive.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
 function launchOneDrivePicker(){
 var options = {
  clientId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", (I put my client ID in here.)
  action: "query",
  multiSelect: true,
  openInNewWindow: true,
  advanced: { 
  redirectUri: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" (I put my redirect URI in here)
  },
  success: function(files) { /* success handler */ },
  cancel: function() { /* cancel handler */ },
  error: function(e) { /* error handler */ }
}
OneDrive.open(options);
}
</script>
<button onClick="launchOneDrivePicker">Open from OneDrive</button>
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? any assistance would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try set action to one of [share | download | query], the action is like a enum, so it can only be set to action="query" for example.

Comment: I tried this and the button is still not opening a window.

Comment: hi, after a second check, have you add the function invocation in your button attribute? I believe <button onClick="launchOneDrivePicker()">Open from OneDrive</button> should make it work. Not sure if you added the '()' or not after the function name.

Comment: It did work thank you! I'm new to this API so it took me all day just to figure out how to authenticate the user haha.